# MVC 4 Contact Form -- I need a dropdown choice between two recipients, will send only to one

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I need to alter a contact form in MVC 4 to give the user two different choices for an email recipient. I originally had a choice between information and comment, now I need to just have a choice between the recipients (1. Resort, or 2. Casino) to receive the submitted comment. I started to change the choice, but wanted to check before I messed up the model and controller.

View - Contact Form

```
<div id="ContactUsFormContainer">

            @using (Html.BeginForm())
            {
                @Html.ValidationSummary()


                @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.ContactRecipient, new[] 
            {
            new SelectListItem() {Value = "Resort Comment"},
            new SelectListItem() {Value = "Casino Comment"}})<br />

                <div class="inputSmBox">
                    *Your First Name<br />
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.FirstName, new { @style = "width: 180px;", @class = "fHandleClass" })
                </div>

                <div class="inputSmBox">
                    *Your Last Name:<br />
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.LastName, new { @style = "width: 180px;" })
                </div>   

                <div class="inputSmBox">
                    *Your Phone Number:<br />
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Phone, new { @style = "width: 180px;" })
                </div>

                <div class="inputSmBox">
                    *Your Email Address:<br />
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Email, new { @style = "width: 180px;" })
                </div>

                <p class="inputSmBox">
                    *Subject<br />
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Subject, new { @style = "width: 400px;" })
                </p>   

                <p class="inputSmBox" style="margin-top: 5px;">
                    *Type your comments below<br />
                    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Comment, new { @style = "width: 400px;" })
                </p>   

                <div class="Clear"></div>
                    <p>
                    <input type="submit" value="" class="submitButton" id="submitButtonStyle" />
                </p>

            }

        </div>
```

View - Thankyou

```
@{
    try {

        WebMail.SmtpServer = "mail.resortdata.com";

        WebMail.From = "no-reply@casino.com";

        WebMail.Send("info@resort.com", "From Resort Casino Website Contact Us Form",
            Model.FirstName + " " + Model.LastName + " has initiated contact with Resort Casino via the website contact form." + "<br /><br />" + "Phone number:" + " " + Model.Phone + "<br /><br />" + "Email address:" + " " + Model.Email + "<br /><br />" + "Subject:" + " " + Model.Subject + "<br /><br />" + "<b>Comment:</b>" + "<br />" + Model.Comment +"<br />");
    }

    catch (Exception) 
    {
        @:<b>Sorry we could not send an email with your contact information.</b>
    }
}            


<h2>Thank you @Model.FirstName for your comment.

    </h2>
```

Controller

```
public ViewResult ContactUsThankYou()
        {
            int hour = DateTime.Now.Hour;
            ViewData["greeting"] = hour < 12 ? "Good Morning!" : "Good Afternoon";
            return View();
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public ViewResult ContactUs()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ViewResult ContactUs(ContactUs ContactUs)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return View("ContactUsThankYou", ContactUs);
            }

            else 
            {
                return View();
            }
        }
```

Model

```
public class ContactUs
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter your first name")]
        [RegularExpression("^[a-zA-Z]+$",
            ErrorMessage = "Please enter valid characters")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter your last name")]
        [RegularExpression("^[a-zA-Z]+$",
            ErrorMessage = "Please enter valid characters")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter your phone #")]
        [RegularExpression(@"((\(\d{3}\) ?)|(\d{3}-))?\d{3}-\d{4}",
            ErrorMessage = "Please enter a valid phone number 555-555-5555")]
        public string Phone { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter your email")]
        [RegularExpression("^[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?",
            ErrorMessage = "Please enter a valid email address all lower case")]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a subject")]
        //[RegularExpression("^[a-zA-Z]+$",
        //    ErrorMessage = "Please enter a subject without odd characters")]
        public string Subject { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter your request or statement in the comment box")]
        [RegularExpression("^[a-zA-Z]+$",
            ErrorMessage = "Please enter valid characters")]
        [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
        public string Comment { get; set; }

    }
```

Thanks

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: How do I add the dropdown choice for recipient and then have it go to the place of choice when the submit button is hit. What do I put in the view, the model, or the controller? I did forget to add the thankyou view where the input of the form is handled - I've added it now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your form and setup works then I think all you have to do is set up a condition on the Model.ContactRecipient   value to project the Webmail.To value.  I have not run this solution but try this below.

```
 @{
try {

   WebMail.SmtpServer = "mail.resortdata.com";

    WebMail.From = "no-reply@casino.com";

 if(Model.ContactRecipient="Resort Comment"){
  Webmail.To = "info@resort.com"
   }
  else
   {
  Webmail.To = "info@casino.com"
    }
    WebMail.Send(Webmail.To, "From Resort Casino Website Contact Us Form",
        Model.FirstName + " " + Model.LastName + " has initiated contact with Resort Casino via the website contact form." + "<br /><br />" + "Phone number:" + " " + Model.Phone + "<br /><br />" + "Email address:" + " " + Model.Email + "<br /><br />" + "Subject:" + " " + Model.Subject + "<br /><br />" + "<b>Comment:</b>" + "<br />" + Model.Comment +"<br />");
}

catch (Exception) 
{
    @:<b>Sorry we could not send an email with your contact information.</b>
  }
   }            


<h2>Thank you @Model.FirstName for your comment. </h2>
```